# Firebug: Stop the HTML inspector window from jumping

Tags: firebug

I've looked around for answers to this problem, but I couldn't find anything related.

This is very stupid problem but I have no idea how to resolve it.

I have a page with a slideshow for example, I open Firebug to inspect the HTML, but when I'm using the HTML inspector panel it then 'jumps' to the section of the slideshow (since a new slide just loaded), I then have to scroll back to where I was, but then Firebug jumps back again when a new slide is loaded.

The only two workarounds I have right now are: Make the Firebug bottom pannel larger or open it in a new window and maximize it. Or right click on the slideshow HTML element and delete it from the page.

Is there a way to have Firebug not jump around the HTML inspector panel while having a script refresh a section of the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a simpler solution: use the firebug's Html dropdown menu.

Comment: Ok, and then what ulu? I don't see anything in that menu related to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm My menu is in Russian so I'm not sure about the English equivalent. Anyway, I've got the top group of options starting with "Show" (or "Display"), then a divider, and the next group goes like "Highlight changes", "Expand changes" and "Scroll to changes" (or maybe it's mutations not changes). Is your menu different? My FireBug is 1.7.0

Comment: Yes, exactly like mine... but I'm still not sure what option I should be looking for in order to stop the code inspector from jumping when a JS action happens.

Comment: Much simpler solution than noomz. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Click on js tab and left there is yellow button , just hit ,it will pause script and hance you can inspect

here in step

> 1. click on script tab (console HTML CSS Script)
> 2. click yellow button left bottom
> 3. click on html,console or what every you want and then click to inspectyou want and then click to inspect

Comment: JapanPro, thanks for your help.

However, your solution requires me to have to click on the Script tab, pause it, and then click the HTML tab, and I have to do this every time I refresh the page, so if I'm constantly uploading changes to the page, I always have to do this process.

Isn't there a way to just have Firebug not jump around the HTML code inspector when a section of the HTML changed?

I'm going to give you a point for this another workaround.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

**THE** solution to this problem is:

1. In the HTML tab, click on the arrow to bring the drop down out.
2. Uncheck "**Scroll Changes Into View**".

FYI, this is the solution in Firebug 1.7.1.

Thanks to **ulu** for this solution.

--

Although crossed out, I'm leaving the former solution here for reference:

<strike>The exact solution for this problem is:</strike>

1. Go to **about:config**
2. Look for **extensions.firebug.scrollToMutations**
3. Double click on it, the Value should say ***false***

That's it, when viewing the HTML code and a change in the DOM happens, the view won't jump to that change :)

Here's more information about Firebug's parameters: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel

Thanks to noomz for pointing me in the right direction for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go to firefox config page by enter url `about:config`,find this values "`extensions.firebug.expandMutations`" and change it to false

Comment: This was almost the solution, but by doing this and a little help from Google, it got me right next to the exact solution for this. See my solution below. I selected your answer as the Accepted Answer :) Thanks for your help noomz.